# How to pass python loop i to sql select top i number of rows

Tags: python, sql, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to python and sql bear with my knowledge.

I want to run a query where I can get top (looped variable) while running sql in python compiler.

Eg

```
For I in range(1,5) :
    Query = " Select top" I" * from sales"
```

So that can get the top 1st row in first I loop and top 2nd row in next I loop and goes on. Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use string replacement as prepared statements will not work

```
for I in range(1,5) : 
    Query = " Select top {} * from sales".forma(I)
```